# How can I increase the limit of 1000 characters at which Hibernate stores Strings as CLOBs?

Tags: java, hibernate

Apparently Hibernate automatically adds the @Lob annotation when the String length exceeds 1000 chars, where would I change that limit? I want VARCHAR2s instead, which Oracle supports up to 4000 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place an @Column(length = X) on the field